# How to Create a Website Programatically in IIS 8 using C# code

Tags: c#

I used the code from below link to create a website in `IIS8` programmatically, but i cant find any website created since I am new to `C#`. A brief clarification would be helpful for me. Most of the codes are for `IIS7`.

[Reference Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/06/09/iis7-sample-code-for-adding-deleting-a-website-programmatically-c-example.aspx)

Comment: http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

Its a sample for managing the iis programmatically. First you should have a real solution to be able to programmatically configure the IIS if thats what you want.

Comment: Is there any code snippets to programattically configure the iis?? can u suggest me??

Comment: Its possible with WMI:
[msdn blog - programmatically starting and stopping ftp sites in iis 7 and iis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/10/03/programmatically-starting-and-stopping-ftp-sites-in-iis-7-and-iis-8.aspx)

Here is some other link that you can check:
[programmatically configuring IIS](http://martinnormark.com/adding-an-application-pool-to-iis7-programmatically/)

Hope those solves your problem..